# Writing JSON in Python

Tags: python, json

I want to append onto an employees history every time they clock in. I have appended within python but cant get it to write back to the JSON file.

```
import json

json_data = open("app.json")
data = json.load(json_data)

for d in data['employees']:
        d['history'].append({'day': 01.01.15, 'historyId': 44, 'time': 12.00})
        json.dump(d['history'])
```

Comment: 1) Show us the input `app.json`. 2) Do you get any error? 3) What is `01.01.15` mean to be?

Comment: Maybe if you get an error `TypeError: dump() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)` that you don't understand, you should think about reading [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dump)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`json.dump()` takes **two** arguments, the Python object to dump and the file to write it to.

Make your changes first, then *after* the loop, re-open the file for writing and write out the **whole** `data` object:

```
with open("app.json") as json_data:
    data = json.load(json_data)

for d in data['employees']:
    d['history'].append({'day': 01.01.15, 'historyId': 44, 'time': 12.00})

with open("app.json", 'w') as json_data:
    json.dump(data, json_data)
```

This essentially replaces the file contents with the JSON-serialised new data structure.